# How can I click a video play button on iPhone with Appium using C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, appium, simulator

I'm using Appium to automate testing on some sites. The page I am testing has a video on it (the video is the only item on the page). Since videos don't auto play on iOS there is a play button, I need to click this play button to continue.
I've used appium inspector to get the xpath of the video, but the webdriver is unable to find it.

Is there an easy way to click the play button of a video through automation with C#? I've spent ages on this and can't get it working.

I'm currently using the Remotewebdriver. I tried to set up the IOSDriver so hopefully I could just click the screen coordinates (since it is dead centre in the page it should be easy) but I'm having many other problems trying to set up the IOSDriver.
I'm currently doing this through the simulator.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxfKB.png)

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally android and ios screen are XML, slimier HTML is for web.

you can use :

```
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

In C# use Console.Writer.

It will print the whole XML of the current screen. Now identify the element and create a Xpath